# How to programmatically un/register POJOs as services in JBoss 4.2.3.GA

Tags: jboss, jndi

I need to be able to circumvent the whole deployer malarkey and programmatically register/unregister (dependency-less) POJOs as services in JBoss.

Currently I'm dynamically creating an MBean interface and registering this with the JBoss MBeanServer, and then registering local/remote with Jndi.

This works ok (I can have a standard service from a vanilla SAR reference one of these service POJOs with the @EJB annotation) - however the container seems to leaves stale references behind as after calling unbind() and unregisterMBean().

Obviously I'm missing something by not dealing with the container in a way it expects, but what am I missing?  Or is there an easier way (can't see much in the way of an API)?

thanks.

Comment: It seems you are performing due diligence on clean up by calling unbind and unregister. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "stale references" ? Additionally, have you looked at using the @Service annotation to create singleton EJBs ? They're pretty much Pojos but they have a clean and well defined lifecycle,  the transactional support of EJBs, an optional JMX management interface and the ability to publish remote and local interfaces into JNDI.

Comment: @Nicholas - I need to programmatically register these POJOs, deploying a SAR or even using the @Service annotation is out of the question.  I can register these POJOs with both JNDI and MBeanServer and the access them in standard @Service annotated services via @EJB - but when I unregister them from JNDI and JMX the reference in @EJB remains, so actually it's not a stale reference but it should be

Comment: Now I got it. In a declarative (non-earcam) POJO registration for ServiceA which is @EJB referenced by ServiceB, when ServiceA is undeployed, ServiceB would go with it. What I am not sure of in your case, ServiceB is still there and you want the @EJB ref to be invalid until a new instance of ServiceA is deployed ? Or something like that ?

Comment: I started fiddling with org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer and org.jboss.ejb3.ServiceContainer to no avail.  Just can't figure out if it's possible to interact with JBoss 4.2.3.GA in a programmatic fashion.  I'd got 95% of the way (in that I could register my own POJO services with JNDI and JMX, and the reference in vanilla JBoss @Service serivces with just @EJB) but as the references aren't cleared up correctly when I call unregister etc this has proved an unusable exercise.
Oh well, I have a very mechanical approach that achieves the same end result but requires a lot of boiler plate code.

Comment: @Nicholas thanks for your input but I won't take any more of your time (this question is incredibly vague but elaboration would require reams of code)